# Venue Search seems to be ignoring CategoryId parameter

Tags: api, foursquare

I'm trying to do some resolution between restaurants in my DB to their respective Foursquare id.  For example, there's a Steakhouse (a subcategory of the Food category) in Penang, MY called 'Suffolk House', but when I specify the categoryId non-Food related venues still show up in the result group.

`https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?categoryId=4d4b7105d754a06374d81259&intent=match&ll=5.4112879000000,100.305271200000&query=Suffolk&client_id=XXXXXXX&client_secret=XXXX`

You'd expect only results belonging withing a category (or subcategory) would come back.  What gives? Is categoryId really a no-op parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `categoryId` parameter is not currently supported for `intent=match`. You can either filter the results by category afterwards, or use a different intent if you need category matches.

Comment: Thanks!  Is there a list somewhere (of do you know from experience) of intents like 'browse' for which categoryId is supported?

Comment: I believe it is supported for all intents other than match